# Prove or give a counterexample to the statement on addition modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or give a counterexample to the statement that for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ then the equation $x+_{n}x+_{n}x=a$ has exactly one solution in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Is this counter example a valid solution?

Let $n=19$ and $a=1$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x+_nx+_n x=a \\
= & 3 x=1
\end{aligned}
$$

This is not possible since $x \notin Z_n$, so we must have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 3 x-19=1 \\
= & 3 x=20
\end{aligned}
$$

This is also not possible, since $x \notin Z_n$. So we have disproven that exactly one solution exist in $Z_n$.

Now I realise that this wrong, because $x=13$ is a solution to this equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
13+_{19}13+_{19}13 & =(26-19)+_{19}19 \\
& =7+_{19}13=(20-19)=1
\end{aligned}
$$

I cant figure out how to rigoussly
prove this without using the modular arithmetic equivalence as we haven't studied it yet

Comment: $3\times 13\equiv 1 \pmod {19}$.

Comment: Could you please explain how my solution is wrong, I learnt this method from the book “ a first course in abstract algebra “ by Farleigh. In it he doesn’t use number theory to compute addition modulo

Comment: I don't understand your method.  If you are trying to solve $3x\equiv 1\pmod {19}$.  You need to solve $3x+19k=1$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$.  You appear to declare that $k$ has to be $1$, but that's simply not true.  Indeed, $(x,k)=(13,-2)$ works.   You certainly don't need any sort of general theory to solve this...$19$ is very small, simply trying all $19$ possible values for $x\pmod {19}$ gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Your counter-example is definitely wrong since you select $n\neq 3$ is a prime and $a=1$. Because $F_p=Z/pZ $ is a field.
Here are some hints for you.

1:Can you show that $x+x+x=a$ is equal to $3x \equiv a \mod n$?

2:Can you show that if $3a\equiv3b \mod n$ under the assumption that $3$ does not divide $n$,then $(a-b)\equiv 0 \mod n$?

3:Can you show the map from $Z_n$ to $Z/nZ$ as $x \rightarrow 3x+nZ$ is actually a bijection?

Let us try to prove these without involving ring theory.$F_p$ mentioned at the very begining can be totally ignored.

Firstly recall that $Z_n$ is a cyclic group of the structure $\{0,a,a+a,\dots ,(n-1)a\}$

Now ,for $ka\in Z_n$,$ka+ka+ka=3ka$ .However,we want the coefficient of $a$ is an integer between $0$ and $n-1$.Since we have $na=0$,we can devide $3k$ by $n$,we have $3k=mn+r,0\leq r\leq n-1$.Therefore,$3ka=ra$.

If $3k_1a=3k_2a$,which means $3k_1=m_1n+r,3k_2=m_2n+r$.We have $$3(k_1-k_2)=(m_1-m_2)n$$

$n$ is not divisible by $3$,hence,$m_1-m_2 $must be divisible by $3$.So $k_1-k_2 = m_0n$ for  an integer $m_0$.Can you tell why $m_0$ must be $0$?

Therefore,map $Z_n\rightarrow Z_n$ given as $x\rightarrow x+x+x$ is injective.$Z_n$ is finite.Try to make some conclusions with "finite" and
"injection".

Comment: But in the book “ a first course in abstract algebra “ by Farleigh, he doesn't use rhese advanced concepts, he uses the method i mentioned in my solution

Comment: Please tell me how can we show point 1 that you menti9ned to be true?

Comment: @BruceHunt , I rewrite it. Will this help?